# Save a sequence (generator) of dictionaries to a CSV file; handling potentially missing keys

Tags: python, csv, export-to-csv

I query an API and get a result as a sequence of dictionaries. The sequence is a generator, which can **not** be converted to a list, because it's possibly too big to fit in memory.

I need to save this into a CSV file. I saw sample code that takes keys from the first record, with the assumption that all the dictionaries have the same keys:

```
import csv
data = [{'name':'Bob','age':25,'weight':200},
        {'name':'Jim','age':31,'weight':180}]
keys = data[0].keys()
with open('people.csv', 'w', newline='')  as output_file:
    dict_writer = csv.DictWriter(output_file, keys)
    dict_writer.writeheader()
    dict_writer.writerows(data)
```

The problem is that some keys might be missing from some records. So, I can not rely on the first record having all possible keys.

For example, let's say, my data is:

```
data = [{'name':'Bob','age':25,'weight':200},
        {'name':'Jim','age':31,'weight':180},
        {'name':'Jane','age':27, 'pets': ['cat', 'dog']},
        {'name':'Dorothy','location':'Oz'},
       ]
```

I would want this result:

```
name,age,weight,pets,location
Bob,25,200,,
Jim,31,180,,
Jane,27,,"['cat', 'dog']",
Dorothy,,,,Oz
```

I know that all records have the unique identifier field,  but other than that, I don't want to make any hard-coded assumptions about field names.

One possibility is to loop through all 100,000 records to get all possible keys. I would have to save the records to a temp file (being generator, I can only loop once). Then loop through that temporary file and create the final file.

Is there a more elegant way?

Comment: Since the data in each row of a CSV must be ordered in the similar manner, I don't think there's any way to avoid making two passes through the data to be able to determine what all the possible fields (keys) there might be.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to iterate twice over the generator. With an appropriate file format, it may be possible to do a single-pass. But with CSV we can't.
What I suggest is to two passes :

- first reading the dictionnaries, writing to a temporary file
- second reading back from the temporary file, writing to the definitive file

There are different ways to do it from there. I choose one where the intermediary data on-disk is the closer to the final one.
What I do is set an **upper bound** on the number of columns there could be, then on the first pass I write a lot of empty columns. These may potentially be filled in later rows with new columns names.
The second pass, knowing the definitive column list, remove the excess from the first one.

```py
import csv
import io
import tempfile


UPPER_BOUND_ON_COLUMNS_NUMBER = 40  # change it


def write_into_csv(out_file: io.TextIOBase, dic_generator) -> None:
    column_names = dict()  # both a list of all known columns names so far, and for each its index in the CSV file
    # first pass
    with tempfile.TemporaryFile(mode="r+t", newline="") as tmp_file:
        tmp_writer = csv.writer(tmp_file)
        for dic in dic_generator:
            # check if there is new columns
            unknown_column_names = sorted(set(dic.keys()).difference(column_names.keys()))  # the `sorted` here is just for reproducability
            for unknown_column_name in unknown_column_names:
                column_index = len(column_names)
                column_names[unknown_column_name] = column_index
            # create an empty row
            row_data = ["" for _ in range(UPPER_BOUND_ON_COLUMNS_NUMBER)]
            # and populate it with the values for this row
            for key, value in dic.items():
                row_data[column_names[key]] = value
            tmp_writer.writerow(row_data)
        assert len(column_names) <= UPPER_BOUND_ON_COLUMNS_NUMBER, f"too many columns ({len(column_names)})"
        # now that we have iterated over the whole file, we know the actual columns
        # so we can remove them from the written file
        tmp_file.seek(0)  # rewind the file
        tmp_reader = csv.reader(tmp_file)
        out_writer = csv.writer(out_file)
        out_writer.writerow(
            name for name, index in sorted(column_names.items(), key=lambda item: item[1])
        )
        for tmp_line in tmp_reader:
            out_writer.writerow(
                tmp_line[:len(column_names)]
            )


if __name__ == '__main__':
    def get_dictionnaries():  # generator
        yield from (
            {'name': 'Bob', 'age': 25, 'weight': 200},
            {'name': 'Jim', 'age': 31, 'weight': 180},
            {'name': 'Jane', 'age': 27, 'pets': ['cat', 'dog']},
            {'name': 'Dorothy', 'location': 'Oz'},
        )


    fake_output_file = io.StringIO()
    write_into_csv(fake_output_file, get_dictionnaries())
    assert fake_output_file.getvalue() == (
        "age,name,weight,pets,location\r\n"
        "25,Bob,200,,\r\n"
        "31,Jim,180,,\r\n"
        "27,Jane,,\"['cat', 'dog']\",\r\n"
        ",Dorothy,,,Oz\r\n"
    ), repr(fake_output_file.getvalue())
```

For illustration, the content of the intermediary file is :

```
25,Bob,200,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
31,Jim,180,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
27,Jane,,"['cat', 'dog']",,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,Dorothy,,,Oz,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
```

This solution uses a lot of disk (nearly twice the size of the final file), may be slow because we have to write, re-read then re-write.
For both these shortcomings, using a custom data format (binary or textual) may be more efficient, but also harder to implement (and debug). If that's the case, please create a new question with performance requirements.